# make a counter (like a binary count) JS

Tags: javascript, logic, task

you need to make a counter like this:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

how to implement this beautifully?

I haven't figured out how to implement this.

Comment: The message broke the position of zeros. they go in 3.

Comment: 0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 111

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at [Number.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method, try something, and if you'll get stuck, then ask a question about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary addition is simple:

- find the rightmost zero bit
- set it to 1
- set all bits right to it to 0

```js
a = Array(3).fill(0)

while (1) {
    console.log(...a)
    let z = a.lastIndexOf(0)
    if (z < 0)
        break
    a[z] = 1
    a.fill(0, z + 1)
}
```

Homework: rewrite without builtins, using only fors and ifs.

Answer (score 2):

- Loop your counter with `while(true)` incrementing it.
- Use [`Number.toString(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to format the counter to the binary form where `2` is a number of bits per a character.
- Use `String.padStart(3, '0')` to make strings 3 character long.
- If the length > 3 `break` the cycle
- Split the string and join with `" "` to add spaces between numbers.

```js
let count = 0;
let result = '';

while(true){
  const text = (count++).toString(2).padStart(3, '0');
  if(text.length > 3) break;
  result += text.split('').join(' ') + '\n';
}

$pre.textContent = result;
```

```html
<pre id="$pre"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea by Alexander to get advantage of padStart to get the desired number of digit. I borrow it to give my version, adaptable to the number of digits.

```js
function binaryCounter(numDigits) {
  if (numDigits <= 0) {
    console.log("Invalid input: Number of digits must be greater than 0");
    return;
  }

  const maxValue = Math.pow(2, numDigits) - 1;

  for (let i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++) {
    const binary = i.toString(2).padStart(numDigits, '0').split('').join(' ');
    console.log(binary);
  }
}

binaryCounter(0);
binaryCounter(2);
binaryCounter(3);
binaryCounter(4);
```